# iOS Catch Debugger Trap (BKPT 3)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, lldb, mach, frida

I have an iOS application I am analyzing/reverse engineering. There is a function I want to intercept with Frida. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem but the function is called at or soon after the app is launched so there is no time for Frida to attach before the function is called.

I am working on an iPhone 5 which is a 32-bit armv7 device. Unfortunately apparently launching applications is broken for Frida on armv7.

Therefore, I tried a long shot that was unsuccessful. I wrote a dylib that swizzles the target method. In the swizzled implementation, I trigger a debugger interrupt (`__asm__('trap')`, I also tried `bkpt 3`). I started the debugserver and connected lldb on my machine to it. I was hoping that the debugserver would intercept the trap from the application but clearly I was wrong.

Does anyone have a) How traps are normally intercepted (by say, the debugger), b) Any information on how debugserver attaches itself to a process, or c) Any other ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `__builtin_trap()`? `raise(SIGINT)`? `asm("svc 0");`? `asm("int 3");`?

Comment: Yes, the trap itself works. I ran it in a test app through Xcode and the Xcode debugger is triggered. What I am having trouble with is how to have debugserver/lldb catch this trap and trigger.

Comment: If you need time for the debugger to attach, why not simply inject a dylib with `raise(SIGSTOP);`?

Comment: I liked the idea but I tried it and debugserver won't attach. It must be that it can only attach when the process is in the running state.

Comment: What happens if you inject `sleep(5000)` or something? Attach the debugger, then the sleep will finish and voila?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. I was hoping for something a bit more elegant but I might have to fall back to that.

Comment: @Brandon I ended up doing this and it works fine. Thanks for the suggestion